# Most efficient method for creating new binary Series based on conditional in Pandas when the old series has missing data?

Tags: python, pandas

What is the most efficient* way to create a new pandas series based on a binary condition when the underlying data is numeric or text, and contains missing elements?

(*efficient means minimizing RAM utilization and time to run on a big Series)

Examples below - is there a single code pattern that is optimal for both numeric and text (and other dtypes)? I have seen other questions on SO suggest `np.where()`, but this gives the wrong answer in the presence of missing data

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# create values
s1 = pd.Series(range(10,30))
# create missing
s1[s1 < 12] = np.NaN

# return new series based on binary condition that respects missing data?
# this does not respect missing data
np.where(s1>18, 'adult','not-adult')  # NaN values evaluate to false
# using series.gt does not help
s1.gt(18)

# pd.cut works for numeric data, but what if the underlying data/conditionals were strings? 
pd.cut(s1, bins=[0,18,100],labels=['Young','Old']) # works for numeric

# string example
s2 = pd.Series(['Saturday','Sunday','Monday',np.NaN])
# np.where
np.where(s2.isin(['Saturday','Sunday']), 'weekend','not weekend')  # NaN values evaluate to false

## What code pattern is efficient/elegant that gives desired behavior?
## Output Series should be NaN wherever input Series is NaN
```

Comment: what do you mean by "respects" missing data? You want it to preserve `NaN`, so your possible values are `True, False, NaN`?

Comment: @ALollz correct, if a value in the input vector is missing, the that value in the output should be missing as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's not a single pattern because each selection is logically different.

Any `==, <, <=, >,` or  `>`  comparison with at least one `NaN` evaluates to `False`. `pandas` is correct in returning `False` for `NaN < 12` because that's the standard. Deviating from this requires your own logic.

With `pd.cut` it's the same logic as above, but a different consequence. You group if `s1` falls within the bins. Since `NaN` is not within any of those bins, `NaN` doesn't get binned, and the output is `NaN`.

In the final case, `NaN` is `not in ['Saturday', 'Sunday']` so it's `False`.